# JPA can run without hibernate provider.???

Tags: hibernate, jpa

early I used JPA to developed ORM for my application. In peristenc.xml , I defined hibernate provider and using Non-JTA-DataSource. JPA can run without hibernate provider.???  then I omit hibernate code in persistence.xml. Then I deployed, In console I'm getting following information.

```
 18:19:56,028 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
    18:19:56,032 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    18:19:56,033 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactor
```

But I didn't mention any where in my apps about hibernate.

** *persistence.xml* *****

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="StudentManagementSystem" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/studentDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>com.dms.entity.student.StudentDetail</class>
        <class>com.dms.entity.student.MarkDetail</class>
        <class>com.dms.entity.student.PRDSemesterDetail</class>
        <class>com.dms.entity.admin.LoginDetail</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

*** Non-JTA- data source ***

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/studentDS" pool-name="studentDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exercise</connection-url>
                    <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>student</user-name>
                        <password>student</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
<driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running your application in JBoss, and Hibernate is the default persistence provider of JBoss. As stated in the spec, the persistence provider is optional in persistence.xml. In this case, the container (JBoss) uses its default provider.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you can specify which JPA provider you want to use putting this in your persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
  ...
</persistence-unit>
```

the example uses eclipse-link as the provider. You must have the provider specific jars in your class path for this to work (eclipse-link, openJPA, hibernate, iBatis, etc)

The messages you are getting are because your server already has an hibernate implementation bundled with it, and that's taken as the default, but you should be able to use the implementation you want just by setting the right provider.

However you are not going to be able to run JPA without any provider, since JPA is not an implementation but just a definition of how persistence should be.